# How do i create the rails 3.1 application using mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How to create a rails 3.1 application using mysql. The following command used to create the project with sqlite database.

```
rails new depot
```

I'd like to use mysql then sqlite. So can anyone tell me how to create a project with mysql.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See help for rails new command

```
rails new --help
```

-d, [--database=DATABASE]

Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db)
                              # Default: sqlite3

Answer (score 11):

You should use:

```
rails new depot -d mysql
```